# json-server not showing URL for JSON data

Tags: javascript, json-server

I am working with `json-server`. I have installed it with `npm install -g json-server` and am watching using

```
json-server --watch db.json
```

I have added `db.json` file in app folder with below data

```
{
    "product": [
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "firstName": "Krish",
        "lastName": "Lee",
        "phoneNumber": "123456",
        "emailAddress": "krish.lee@learningcontainer.com"
      },
      {
        "userId": 5,
        "firstName": "jone",
        "lastName": "mac",
        "phoneNumber": "111111111",
        "emailAddress": "jone.mac@learningcontainer.com"
      }
    ]
  }
```

but only `http://localhost:3000/` is working. It shows

```
Congrats!
You're successfully running JSON Server
✧*｡٩(ˊᗜˋ*)و✧*｡

Resources
/posts 1x
/comments 1x
/profile object
To access and modify resources, you can use any HTTP method:

GET POST PUT PATCH DELETE OPTIONS

undefined
Documentation
README

To replace this page, create a ./public/index.html file.
```

`http://localhost:3000/product` is not working. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you see any output from `json-server` when it starts up? I see it list the resource endpoints, including `http://localhost:3000/product` which works fine. Your posted JSON is malformed, with an invalid trailing comma, but I assume that's an artifact of cutting it down to post (because `json-server` errors out if given malformed JSON). Please give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I have updated my question. Cound you please check.

Comment: They're the defaults, presumably you also see "Oops, db.json doesn't seem to exist"? Post (and read!) *all* of the output you're given.

Comment: And have you double-checked the actual content of the db.json it's loading? The first time you run it, if it can't find the file you asked for, it writes out its own defaults for you to edit. When that happened, it would have told you it was doing that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - It's working now. another db.json was getting created in different level. I didn't notice that before. Now able to post my own json and get the url browse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you try to run `json-server@0`, if it can't find the supplied source, [`load.js`](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/blob/913473f3042797beec85b4c2903ea860aec4f429/src/cli/utils/load.js#L19-L24) writes out the default example for you:

```
> json-server --watch db.json


  \{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading db.json
  Oops, db.json doesn't seem to exist
  Creating db.json with some default data

  Done

  Resources
  http://localhost:3000/posts
  http://localhost:3000/comments
  http://localhost:3000/profile

  Home
  http://localhost:3000
```

On subsequent runs, because the file now exists, the server seems to be starting up just fine but isn't using the `db.json` file you think it is. For that reason, this seems like a bit of a misfeature.

I opened [a PR](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/pull/1174) to require this behaviour to be explicitly requested; based on the prerelease `-alpha` versions it looks like this automatic creation won't be a feature of `json-server@1`.

Answer (score 1):

db.json is supposed to be set up in in the root folder? you indicated you put yours in the app folder.

Answer (score 0):

At initial the JSON-server must be started from the root folder.
ex : if you are using VS code editor click on the folder that consist the data in JSON format and right click on that folder and open it in integrated terminal and try : > json-server --watch db.json and it will be working fine.

In case of directly calling the Json-server, it will initialise the default data on localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the PATH of `db.json` file like below

```json
"serve-json": "json-server --watch ./src/db.json --port 5000"
```

now use the comments in terminal `npm run serve-json`

it will navigate port 5000